# Has Dreamweaver CS5 been deleting local files instead of remote files?

Tags: file, ftp, dreamweaver, flash-cs5, delete-file

As scary as it sounds.

I select a remote file, I hit delete. Instead of deleting the selected remote file, Dreamweaver chooses to delete the currently selected LOCAL file(s) - even if they're unrelated.

**EDIT:** I am not able to 'deselect' the soon-to-be-deleted LOCAL file, not that I should have to. Didn't work this way in CS3.

The only way I caught this at all, is because DW tried to delete a file (LOCAL file in screenshot - to the right of the image) which had site links. Thank dog it had site links. Shame about all of my other work which I haven't found yet.

Screenshot attached, describing the steps I took. Also to note, I did search prefs and site prefs etc to see if there was a 'Wreak Havoc Randomly Upon Deletion' checkbox - there was nothing of the sort.

Adobe hasn't answered my for weeks now, am about to lodge a request but figured I'd start here instead of going through that ordeal.

Thanks for any help/thoughts.

[Screenshot is quite large - dual monitors capturing all of the prob in situ. http://codefinger.co.nz/projects/fpx/mod/xeditor/dw_cs5_localFileDeletion_lame.gif](http://codefinger.co.nz/projects/fpx/mod/xeditor/dw_cs5_localFileDeletion_lame.gif)

Comment: Interesting issue, but belongs on http://superuser.com - I don't really see anyone being able to answer this because it seems like a legitimate bug. You'd actually be better off at the Adobe Support Forums, even if their responses seem slow.

Comment: Why superuser? The FAQ states it's okay to ask questions relating to `software tools commonly used by programmers` here...

Comment: It's like tumbleweeds from Adobe, sorry if this does end up being the wrong place to post this question - but I'm currently answerable to some nasty, efficient managers... it just seems so basic that I feel I must be missing some giant global pref button somewhere.

Comment: @MrXexxed: But this is a question that a programmer wouldn't be able to answer... It's a bug in the program. He's obviously shown the answer to be "yes" so there really isn't any question left. I doubt even the people at Super User could solve this, it's just something he's going to have to keep bugging Adobe about until they fix it. @Danjah: I do believe you can still hold the Ctrl key and click on the file to manually deselect it. It's not a very good solution, but should work out until it gets fixed. Remember that just because they don't respond doesn't mean they didn't hear you.

Comment: Fair enough yo, and you're right it just does look like a really lame bug. Thanks for the comments anyway fellas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getting this too.  Quick workaround.  If you have dreamweaver show just the remote site the delete action works as it should (ie it deletes the remote file).  I'm not keen on this view but for now it'll be a case of using it to delete remote stuff.  Hope this is fixed soon - do any of you know if there's an 'alert me' function on an Adobe bug report? Cheers Andy

Comment: Thanks for weighing in there Andy, if you find an answer to your Q re; bug alerts - patch me in!

Answer (score 1):

I have come to the conclusion that 'BACKSPACE' deletes remote files, and the 'DEL' key deletes local files. I too figured this out the hard way, and deleted some important files. I haven't seen anything in the new features on why this was changed like this, but it may have been nice to let people know of the change.

Comment: Ya, I agree. If its a bug, fair dues (though a lame one). If it isn't a bug then I agree completely. I've filed a bug report on it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Adobe is aware of this bug and will be addressing it in there next update. There is a simple work around where you don't have to change views.

1. Select the remote file, files or folder that you want to work with.
2. Click the refresh button at the top of the files panel.
3. Select the remote file, files or folders that you want to work with a second time.
4. Right click and choose "Delete".